# how to send a list vertically in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
const Discord = require ('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()

const PREFIX = "!";

var USER = []
var GAME = []
var check = false
var show = 0
var my_list = ["potato","banana","apple","pineapple"]

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('connect as ' + client.user.tag)
    let guild = client.guilds.get('636849722484850688')
})

client.on('message', message =>{
    let agrs = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    let user = message.author;
    const targetMention = message.mentions.users.first();
    switch (agrs[0]){
        case 'list':
            message.channel.send(my_list)
        break;
    }
})
```

how do i make the bot send out my list one by one vertically?

this is the list:

1. potato
2. banana
3. apple
4. pineapple

these are the options

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.proptotype.map()` and `Array.prototype.join()` to get a formatted string of your list.

For example, this:

```
message.channel.send(my_list.map((i) => `${my_list.indexOf(i)+1}. ${i}`).join("\n"));
```

Will output:

```
1. potato
2. banana
3. apple
4. pineapple
```

Answer (score 0):

Since discord is served in a markdown like syntax, you can just use a map to write the list like you would in markdown:

```js
var my_list = ["potato", "banana", "apple", "pineapple"]

const list = my_list.map((item, i) => `${i + 1}. ${item}`).join("\r\n")
console.log(list)

// message.channel.send(list)
```